# Having trouble parsing "file server commands" in C

Tags: c, string, parsing, strchr

The commands will be in the form:

> command filename bytes\nfile_contents

I'm having no trouble separating ADD, filename, and the number of bytes, but I am not sure how I can get the remainder of the server command, namely the file contents.

This is how I am parsing each command. Currently to get the file contents I am getting the left most char* that is '\n'. the file_contents char* never changes from NULL.

```
command = strtok( message, " \n" );
file = strtok( NULL, " " );
bytes = atoi( strtok( NULL, "\n" ) );
file_contents = strchr( message, '\n' );
```

Any suggestions for how to get the file contents?

Comment: Are you sure you have a true newline (ASCII 10 0xa) embedded in bytes`\n`file_contents or is that simply a `backslash` followed by `n`?

Comment: If it is a newline, it is consumed by your `bytes` call, causing `file_contents = strchr( message, '\n' );` to point to the newline at the end of message (if present). Using `strtok` again should suffice `file_contents = strtok( NULL, "\n" );` (ending on the newline or null-terminating char (if no newline present).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do

```
command = strtok( message, " \n" );
file = strtok( NULL, " " );
bytestr = strtok( NULL, "\n" );
bytes = atoi( bytestr );
file_contents = bytestr + strlen(bytestr) + 1;
```

assuming that `file_contents` and `bytestr` are both `char *`.